# Building rpm, overriding _topdir, but getting BuildRequires deps?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I have a `libfoo-devel` rpm that I can create, using the trick to override `_topdir`.  Now I want to build a package "`bar`" which has a BuildRequires '`libfoo-devel`".  I can't seem to find the Right Way to get access to the contents of `libfoo-devel` without having to install it on the build host.  How should I be doing it?

EDIT:

My build and target distros are both SuSE.

I prefer solutions that don't require `mock`, since I believe SuSE does not include it in its stock repo.

Subsequent EDIT:

I believe that the answer I seek is in the `build` package. Perhaps it's SuSE's answer to `mock`? Or it's the distributed version of the oBS service?

> DESCRIPTION
>
> build is a tool to build SuSE Linux
>   RPMs in a safe and clean way. build
>   will install a minimal SuSE Linux as
>   build system into some directory and
>   will chroot to this system to compile
>   the package. This way you don't risk
>   to corrupt your working system (due to
>   a broken spec file for example), even
>   if the package does not use BuildRoot.
>
> build searches the spec file for a
>   BuildRequires: line; if such a line is
>   found, all the specified rpms are
>   installed. Otherwise a selection of
>   default packages are used. Note that
>   build doesn't automatically resolve
>   missing dependencies, so the specified
>   rpms have to be sufficient for the
>   build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you really don't need `libfoo-devel` installed to build package `bar` the most sensible alternative would be to remove `libfoo-devel` from the BuildRequires directive (and maybe put the requirement where it belongs).

However, if you cannot do that for some reason, create a "development" rpm database.  Basically it involves using `rpm --initdb --root /path/to/fake/root`.  Then populate it with all of the "target packages" of your standard distro installation.

That's a lot of `rpm --install --root /path/to/fake/root --justdb package-name.rpm` commands, but maybe you can figure out a way to copy over your `/var/lib/rpm/*` database files and use those as a starting point.  Once you have the alternative rpm database, you can fake the installation of the libfoo-devel package with a --justdb option.  Then you'll be home free on the actual rpm build.

Comment: The headers and the so from libfoo are required for bar to build.  So you're saying I'll need `libc`, `sh`, `cp` and all my friends installed before I can even get started?  This sounds so unbelievably burdensome that it must indicate that I'm "doing it wrong."  So forget my prerequisites, what should I be doing?  If I need to be superuser, it's not particularly convenient.  But maybe that's the most natural/appropriate way to do it.  What's the `rpm` idiom here?

Comment: I'm just offering a solution, not an easy one.  The easy one is obvious, install the devel package.  After all, your bar rpm package NEEDS it to build, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does, but I would prefer to avoid tainting the build host with any of these dependencies.  I'd like my build host's config to be static or at least well-controlled.  I guess it seems my use case is exceptional.

Comment: Brian, you can remove the rpms post-build, and if you don't have root access you should be able to get sudo access from your administrator for the sole purpose of installing / removing these rpms. Anyway, you shouldn't be working around the build system's requirements through trickery.  If your case is exceptional, it seems pretty ordinary from this side of the fence.  You just need to feel a little more pain before you find the easy ways out. If install and removes aren't clean enough for you, you need a build system which can roll back a vm to a pre-install snapshot.

Comment: Edwin, you're right -- I should be able to restore the system's state through various means.  But doesn't it strike you as odd that I should need to be the superuser in order to solve this problem?  I can easily get sudo or even run the build as root, I just don't think I should need to.  Does `dpkg` have similar behavior in this regard?  Ultimately, if this is really the Right Way, then I'll just have to get on with it.  The `chroot`-ed options like `build` or `mock` are semi-appealing ways to achieve my goal (though sadly you still need to have superuser access).

Comment: Installing / removing software is one of the few tasks that can disrupt every user of the system, so why not assigning this task to the superuser?  You don't think you need it, and that's fine.  What you really need is some sort of repository you can manipulate, like one that you personally, privately own.  Oh wait, that's an independent RPM database, owned by you (and not the superuser).  If you want a solution hand crafted to fit your requirements, you have to pay the price of the hand-crafting.

Comment: That's fair.  I just wish rpm addressed this need without handcrafting required because I think it's not quite unique.  I don't need libfoo-devel installed to the system, I only need access to its header files and shared library in order to build my package.  `rpm`'s limitations in this regard seem to cause other problems.  For example, I think it's a totally realistic scenario for one user on this system to build bar-1.2 against libfoo-devel-3.4 while someone else is building bar-1.1 against libfoo-devel-3.3.  So now I need to add some mutual exclusion to protect against this collision?

Comment: RPM handles building against "anything past 1.1" and "anything between 1.1 and 1.4" so perhaps you are setting your requirements to be too specific.  If you're using the library, odds are you are only using a small part of the library, a part which might not have changed between the two releases.

Answer (score 1):

If neither mock nor the [openSUSE Build Service](https://build.opensuse.org/) are a viable choice then you will have to buckle down and install the package, either directly or in a chroot; the package provides files that the SRPM packager has decided are required to build, and hence is in the `BuildRequires` tag.

Comment: Right, I should say that I'm authoring both `libfoo` and `bar`.  I don't think I can use oBS but I'll consider mock.  I must say, between the `buildroot` and `_topdir`, it's pretty confusing to imagine where the chroot would fit in.  I was hoping I could convince `rpmbuild` to install a list of packages, or I could convince `rpm` to install to my buildroot.

Comment: Installing to the buildroot won't help; that's where the exploded SRPMs are, but they still require the BR RPMs to be installed normally.

Comment: Can I groan now?  I feel like I either should lump all of my libfoo, bar and baz business into one mega-rpm, or I have to jump through significant hoops in order to get it to build as non-superuser.